# Google OAuth2 JS can't get Authorization Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-authentication, google-oauth

I have a custom Google Sign In button in React (follows branding guidelines) that I need to implement into a web app. The android app already has Google Sign In implemented with the BE and requires the authorization code to be sent to the BE. I seem to have trouble accessing the authorization code (I can get the access token, id, and id_token fairly easily though).

I initialize as such:

```
static googleInit (googleSignInID) {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        ThirdPartyLogInApi.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            client_id: `${googleSignInID}.apps.googleusercontent.com`,
        })
    })
}
```

In my React component, I attach a click handler to a React ref (as I've seen in other stackoverflow problems).

```
componentDidMount () {
    // element, options, success, failure
    ThirdPartyLogInApi.auth2.attachClickHandler(
        this.button,
        {},
        this.onGoogleSuccess,
        this.setProcessingToFalse
    );
}
```

In the success callback (this.onGoogleSuccess), I am able to call googleUser.getBasicProfile() to get user information and googleUser.getAuthResponse(true) to get id_token and access_token, but I need the authorization code too.

I'm at my wits end with Google's documentation on this - can someone point me in the right direction? I don't want to switch the entire auth flow to use gapi.auth2.authorize, as I do need the user information.

Thanks

EDIT: Is it even possible to access the authorization code? It seems like Google abstracts away that step and just returns the id_token right away. I just need something that looks like:
4/RQFWJLGd3sJQrgxuRaguzJy2yiUV4fAqVGftRSUYuqc